# By using transaction.atomic, are all ACID properties met?

Tags: django, transactions, acid

I'm working on a Django based web application and I'm wanting to make my Django database transactions ACID compliant. However I'm wondering if this is fully achieved by using **transaction.atomic**? Obviously, Atomicity is achieved here but are the other 3 properties also achieved? If not, what steps can I take to achieve those 3 properties?
Any thoughts and explanations would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce my opinion.
I think while using transaction.atomic() to meet the **Atomicity** property
we together use the **Durability** property because .atomic() provides the .commit() property which is used automatically if transaction happens successfully.
Next, **Isolation** is provided by using the manager context while transaction.atomic() is used.
And **Consistency** is provided by field constraints of your Model.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).